# Android: Open and resume via actions (ie. scanning NFC tag)

Tags: android, android-activity

Short version:
I'm looking for a way to launch an application via an action (like scanning an NFC Tag) that will bring upp the application. And if there are already an activity in the background it should bring it up.

I'm a bit confused by tasks and activity history.

Long version:
I'm building an app with NFC support. I have the launch activity, LoginActivity, for logging the user in and another activity, MainActivity, for everything else after the login process.

I can scan an NFC Tag to log in. But I would also like to scan an NFC Tag to bring up the application if it does not have focus. I would like it to either start the application and bring up the LoginActivity which would be the default behavior. Or if the application is running in the background I would like it to just resume which most often would mean resuming MainActivity.

I have configured the application to listen for NFC scan actions and Android is able to choose the application as launcher for the action. But the problem is that I don't know how to make it resume the activity, if any, or just start the application with the launcher activity if it's not started yet. I can get one of them working.

The closest I get to what I want is to have it open the LoginActivity if I scan the tag when the application is in the background. And if I scan again on this LoginActivity it brings up the MainActivity (if I was previously logged in after running the app "normally" without a tag).
I've experimented quite a bit.

Running "adb shell dumpsys activity" gives me this output after I have fully logged in to the application once and then minimized it and scanned an NFC tag:

```
Running activities (most recent first):
  TaskRecord{44f7d8d0 #565 A=com.android.nfc U=0 sz=1}
    Run #3: ActivityRecord{434997e8 u0 com.example.admin/.activities.LoginActivity t565}
  TaskRecord{448674c8 #564 A=com.example.admin U=0 sz=2}
    Run #2: ActivityRecord{430afbc0 u0 com.example.admin/.activities.MainActivity t564}
    Run #1: ActivityRecord{430889b8 u0 com.example.admin/.activities.LoginActivity t564}
  TaskRecord{441daf90 #305 I=com.android.settings/.Settings$DataUsageSummaryActivity U=0 sz=1}
    Run #0: ActivityRecord{43d9f730 u0 com.android.settings/.Settings$DataUsageSummaryActivity t305}
```

If I scan the NFC Tag again I get this after the MainActivity appears:

```
Running activities (most recent first):
  TaskRecord{448674c8 #564 A=com.example.admin U=0 sz=2}
    Run #3: ActivityRecord{430afbc0 u0 com.example.admin/.activities.MainActivity t564}
  TaskRecord{44f7d8d0 #565 A=com.android.nfc U=0 sz=1}
    Run #2: ActivityRecord{434997e8 u0 com.example.admin/.activities.LoginActivity t565}
  TaskRecord{448674c8 #564 A=com.example.admin U=0 sz=2}
    Run #1: ActivityRecord{430889b8 u0 com.example.admin/.activities.LoginActivity t564}
  TaskRecord{441daf90 #305 I=com.android.settings/.Settings$DataUsageSummaryActivity U=0 sz=1}
    Run #0: ActivityRecord{43d9f730 u0 com.android.settings/.Settings$DataUsageSummaryActivity t305}
```

This is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:name="AdminApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.admin.activities.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
    >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.admin.activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
    >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="intent.my.action"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name="com.example.admin.xmpp.XmppService"/>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the best way to solve this is to set the DEFAULT category for NFC Tags to the Activity that will be used most or is the most convinient to handle the tag from and then have the logic to do what is the wanted outcome.

In my case this is to have it default to the MainActivity and do a check there if what we need is set. If not, open the LoginActivity. I stored the last NFC Tag Intent within the application and made it possible to read it from the LoginActivity.
For MainActivity:

```
// Displays login using NFC Tag if tag is read without any active session.
if (((AdminApplication) this.getApplication()).getUserToken() == null && getIntent().getAction().equals("android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED")) {
    ((AdminApplication) this.getApplication()).setIntent(getIntent());
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
    return;
}
```

And for LoginActivity:

```
Intent intent = ((AdminApplication) this.getApplication()).getIntent();
if (intent != null) {
    processNfcTagRead(intent);
    return;
}
```